# Как проверить email на валидность?

Tags: java, android

Как во многих аппликациях у меня при регистрации юзера есть поле для ввода `email` адреса... Так вот перед отправкой на сервер я просто хочу сделать обычную проверку на содержание в нем `@` и `.`

Для этого у меня есть `listener` на форме который и запускается когда юзер ввел данные. Выглядит это вот так

```
View.OnFocusChangeListener focusListener = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

email = etEmail.getText().toString();

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (!hasFocus) {
            if (email.contains("@") && email.contains(".")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "valid", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no valid", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
};
```

Я не могу понять почему но вне зависимости от того есть ли в поле для ввода допустимые знаки или их нет, или поле вообще пустое, ВСЕГДА показывается `valid` ...

Я думал, поможет строчка в XML файле в самом `EditText`, но она я так понял вообще не играет роли и нужна для красоты

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/etEmail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

   ---->>   android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            />
```

Пробовал сделать так, но тоже не работает(в любом случае показывает valid)

```
View.OnFocusChangeListener focusListener = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (!hasFocus) {
            if (isValidEmail(email)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "valid", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no valid", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
};

private boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence target) {
    return !TextUtils.isEmpty(target) &&
            android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches();
}
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Не хочу показаться занудой, но на мой взгляд лучший способ проверить валидность почтового ящика, отправить на него письмо с каким-нибудь кодовым набором букв и ссылкой для активации. И если есть доступ к ящику из приложения, то выдёргиваем нжные данные и валидируем. Если нет доступа, предложить юзеру самому ввести код или пройти по ссылке.

Comment: inputType роляет для того, чтобы клавиатура менялась в нужное русло) например, если в edit указать тип email, то клавиатура поменяется и для быстрого набора покажет собачку @.

Comment: Отправить почту на этот email. Не знаю есть ли функция проверки существования почтового ящика, но вроде сервер должен ругнуться, когда ящика нет. Надо посмотреть протокол SMTP, главное вовремя прервать связь с сервером, чтобы не сдать себя фактической отправкой письма.

Comment: `email = etEmail.getText().toString();` в первом примере выполнится в момент создания экземпляра анонимного класса, т.е. там всегда будет одно значение. Во втором примере не видно, где устанавливается `email`, но, наверное, та же проблема. Внесите получение текста в `onFocusChange`

Comment: @zRrr да, спасибо! Я уже пофиксил

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public final static boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence target) {
    return !TextUtils.isEmpty(target) && android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches();
}
```

**P. S.** Нашел в гугле за 19 секунд. А вам слабо погуглить?

Comment: Я так понимаю сюда `CharSequence target` я должен передать майл который мне нужно проверить и он будет проверяться на валидность согласно регулярных выражений... А я хотел просто проверить свой `EditText` на содержание в нем `@` и `.` я находил много примеров с проверкой таким образом

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, заголовок вашего вопроса выглядит так: **Как проверить email на валидность?**. Не значит ли это, что вы *хотите проверить имейл на валидность?*

Comment: @metalurgus это не вам, а дополнение к вашему ответу. Промахнулся, сонный понедельник, в комменты к вопросу надо было)

Comment: @metalurgus а вы читаете только заголовок? Прочтите первые 3 строки вопроса я специально там обьяснил. И ваше предложение не работает, я добавил описание к вопросу. Что не так?

Comment: metalurgus Вам правильное решение предложил. Проверять строку на наличие собаки и точки будет вам говорить, что email типа @@dhgldkjhd...@...ru валидный.. Попробуйте сей метод просто вызвать из кода типа isValidEmail("fds@dgfdj@.ru") и проверьте тру или фолс он вернет

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, а вы в `Toast` выведите так же валидируемую строку. Может вы строку не ту проверяете? Чтобы получилось `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), email + " is valid", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: Слабак тот кто ищет решение в гугле. А Молодец тот кто сам придумывает, чьи решения и ищут в гугле.

Comment: Между прочим @@... вполне валидный адрес. Просто такие блатные адреса на серверах отключают, потому что криворукие программисты не умеют с ними обращаться, и блатной хозяин адреса страдает. Нельзя обижать хороших людей

Comment: @Sergey, Очередной молодец изобретает в этом вопросе очередную попытку изобрести очередной велосипед. Величайшим преймуществом владеет тот программист, кто способен повторно использовать опыт (неважно, свой или чужой).

Comment: Молодец не изобретает велосипед, он тренируется. И имеет шансы придумать что-то лучшее. Можно у отличника списать домашнее задание, но грамотнее ты же не станешь.

Comment: @Sergey, мне интересно узнать, какой у вас опыт разработки с такими мыслями? Или вы может работаете преподавателем в ВУЗе по программированию, и никогда в жизни не разрабатывали реальные проекты?

Comment: Достаточный, что бы проверки на валидность выполнять самому. И ещё остался интерес узнать как это всё работает внутри. А в ВУЗе я хотел бы быть великим математиком, а не каким-то там программистом. Поэтому на вольных хлебах

Comment: @Sergey простите а вы можете сходу например написать регулярку по Стандарту? Или как вы проверяете корректность e-mail ? RFC 2822 к примеру.

Comment: Я стандарт не помню. Не за чем мне это. Сходу не напишу. Да и вроде нигде не кричал, что напишу сходу и обязательно регулярку. Не всё знаете ли регулярками покрывается.

Comment: Только почему-то на эту тему написан ряд статей, и основной тезис - нужно выбирать между вменяемым кодом и качеством проверки. И на 100% реализацию Стандарта практически нигде не используют.

Comment: Не могу знать. Спросите у авторов статей как они такие тезисы придумывают. И в тоже время есть почтовые сервера вроде как вполне стандартные

Comment: Вот вы нагуглили функцию, которая проверяет адрес, вы что исходники смотрите какой там вменяемый код? Фу, да эту функцию какой-то невменяемый ботан раскатал по стандарту на три листа, какая гадость. поищу-ка исходник в одну строку.